# Offline page in SharePoint

Tags: custom-web-app

I have a web application that is essentially a table of contents for PDF documents that uses appcache to work offline.

I would like to put the documents in SharePoint so that they can be easily updated along with the web application files and manifest as well as being protected.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through a variety of posts I have found a way to make this work with SharePoint.  I am not sure if this is the only approach that works, but this approach fulfilled my needs and thought I would share.

Create your web application and test on a web server.  I found this quicker then working directly in SharePoint.

When you are ready to put it in SharePoint:

1. Create a new blank site using SharePoint Designer
2. In the Pages library, import your web app, matching your directory structure.
3. Set the initial page of your web page as the site home page.  Note: the file extension must be aspx.

Some items to note:

1. The web application and all assets need to be located in the same domain.  For example, in my case, I was linking to documents that were in my personal site and had the web app in the top level site.  Because the domain name differed, and the URL uses SSL, the documents would not cache.  I had to move the documents into the top level as well.
2. When opening on a Mobile device, I found I had to include at the end of the URL ?mobile=0.  I then saved to the Home screen for easy access.
3. The first launch from the home screen on my mobile device required me to be online so that I could authenticate with SharePoint and allow the cache to fully download.  I was then able to go offline and access the web app at anytime.